# Issue compiling Bootstrap 4 Alpha 5 on Windows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, twitter-bootstrap-4, scss-lint

I downloaded the bootstrap 4 alpha 5 source files on my windows 10 machine. I unzipped the folder to my downloads folder and before making any changes I wanted to see how it builds. So I open a command prompt with admin privileges and ran "npm install". It ran and said some things were deprecated and and I got this at the bottom:

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency
> /chokidar/fsevents: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating
> system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.15

It said optional so I didn't think much of it so then I ran "grunt" and got the following error:

> Running "scsslint:core" (scsslint) task Warning: bundleExec options
> set but no Bundler executable found in your PATH. More info:
> https://github.com/ahmednuaman/grunt-scss-lint  Use --force to
> continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

In order to fix it I tried change all modules to in the packages folder to * for version just to get latest but it still didn't work.

I want to emphasize I didn't make any changes to the bootstrap 4 files, I am just trying to compile a fresh download.

Comment: So it says "no Bundler executable found in your PATH". Did you install `ruby` and `bundler`?

Comment: I did not, is there a bootstrap doc on how to set up all the pieces or at least telling us what the prerequisites are so I can set it up myself?

Comment: Yes, it is here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools#tooling-setup